# Disable forgot gate of LSTM network

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working with the LSTM network in Pytorch and I want forgot gate and output gate of the LSTM to be disabled. This is for a particular reason in my research. I mean, even though the gate is present in the network, all data should be flown through or completely delete the gates. One idea I can think of setting the bias term of both the gates to a large value and prevent from updating (Setting trainable == False) so that upon taking the sigmoid, the gate will always output value 1. But I don't know how to do this. I also welcome any other easy approach as well. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks :)